# Create a new div on top of the old div onclick (+) without floating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my current menu. I want that whenever I click on the (+) white button next to "plotting data", another plotting data tab that looks similar appears on top of the old one. Intuitively, if I click the (X) in plotting data div, that newly opened div will be closed and I will go back to the old plotting data div.

[(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clWlo.png)

I have tried offset and setting style as absolute, but the newly opened tab floats instead of being static like the original one.

JavaScript:

```
var i = 0

function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('duplicator' + i) 
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true)
    clone.id = "duplicator"+ ++i
    clone.onclick = duplicate
    
    var topp = original.offsetTop
    clone.style.top = topp 
    original.style.position="absolute"
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tools-date-selection">
    <div class="analysis-tools">
        <h1>Analysis Tools</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="analysis-time">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Start</th>
                    <th>End</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tr>
                <td nowrap>
                    <input type="date" placeholder="current-date" />
                    <input type="time" />
                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    <input type="date" />
                    <input type="time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="analysis-tag-selection">
    <div class="tag-selector">
        <h1>Experiments</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tag-selector">
        <h1>Tags</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tag-selector">
        <h1>Variables</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="plot-button">
    <button id="plot-btn">Plot</button>
</div>
```